# Picture Library, Thumbnail and Web Images not being created

Tags: 2010, picture-library

I'm running `SharePoint 2010 14.0.6120.5006 (April 2012 CU Refresh)`

I've created a Picture Libary at https://sharepoint.domain.com/sites/MyCollection/Pics

I've uploaded an image to the libary and it's visible at https://sharepoint.domain.com/sites/MyCollection/Pics/d1.jpg

However, the Thumbnail and Web Image versions are not getting created. IE, these files don't exist:

- https://sharepoint.domain.com/sites/MyCollection/Pics/_t/d1_jpg.jpg
- https://sharepoint.domain.com/sites/MyCollection/Pics/_w/d1_jpg.jpg

I've tried uploading jpgs, pngs, very large files, checking them in/out, but the Thumbnail and Web Image versions are not getting automatically created for me. I've tried re-creating the picture library and various other types of the libraries, but nothings working.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your Timer job running?

Comment: Yes, I know this because I regularly get timer alerts

Comment: Did any one help you resolve this? I'm having the exact same issue!!!

Comment: @Kate Nope, I never solved this issue and just worked around it.

Answer (score 1):

have you set it up?

http://suryapulipati.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-display-thumbnail-view.html

or

http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/01/28/automatically-generating-thumbnail-images-in-sharepoint.aspx

hope it guides you into the right direction :)

Comment: Unfortunately these don't help. I don't completely understand the first link, but that seems to be creating a custom user control to display the thumbnails. I had already found the second link. The first line it says `When you upload images to a SharePoint picture library three images are actually stored.`. My problem is that only one image is being stored.